# what is the Euler rotation convention in truevision3d?

Tags: geometry, 3d

In what axis order are Euler angles rotated in the graphics
API true vision 3d (tv3d)? I haven't been able to find it
in any documentation.

Comment: // , What documentation have you looked at, so far?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the Z-X-Y convention (rotate around z-axis first, second x, third y.
If anyone can verify this, and/or that there are no ambiguities between different rotation functions, or have other information, that would be helpful.